# Match filtering in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a simple match filtering operation on a data set in python (so I tried doing conjugation followed by convolution). However, an error message is showing in the convolution function saying `object too deep for desired array`.  Below is the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np 
import cPickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('meteor2.pkl', 'rb') as f:     
    data = cPickle.load(f)  
    vlt = data['vlt'] 
    mfilt=np.conjugate(vlt) 
    mfilt1=np.convolve(vlt,mfilt,mode='full')  
    #mfilt=np.conjugate(vlt)
    #mfilt1=np.convolve(vlt,mfilt,'same') 
    r = data['r'] 
    t = data['t'] 
    codes = data['codes'] 
    freqs = data['freqs'] 
    ch0_db = 10*np.log10(np.abs(mfilt1[:, 0, :])**2) 
    plt.figure() 
    plt.imshow(ch0_db.T, vmin=0, origin='lower', cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,aspect='auto')   
    plt.title('All pulses') 
    plt.figure() 
    plt.imshow(ch0_db[3::5, :].T, vmin=0, origin='lower', cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,aspect='auto')
    plt.title('Minimum sidelobe coded-pulses')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: This post started out with broken indentation, and the edits haven't exactly resolved the issue. Please look at your submitted code again and fix it so that what we're seeing matches what you're actually running.

Comment: Assuming you fix the code as @Cairnarvon suggests, please also add a minimal dataset (hopefully just a random numpy array) that reproduces the error and allows us to better debug it.

Answer (score 1):

[`np.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) does *one-dimensional* convolution, so in this line:

```
mfilt1=np.convolve(vlt,mfilt,mode='full')
```

you'll get that error if either `vlt` or `mfilt` is not 1-D.  For example,

```
In [12]: x = np.array([[1,2,3]])  # x is 2-D

In [13]: y = np.array([1,2,3])

In [14]: np.convolve(x, y, mode='full')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-9bf37a14877a> in <module>()
----> 1 np.convolve(x, y, mode='full')

/home/warren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in convolve(a, v, mode)
    822         raise ValueError('v cannot be empty')
    823     mode = _mode_from_name(mode)
--> 824     return multiarray.correlate(a, v[::-1], mode)
    825 
    826 def outer(a,b):

ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

It looks like you want 2-D (or higher) convolution.  `scipy` has a few options:

- [scipy.ndimage.convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html)
- [scipy.signal.convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html)
- [scipy.signal.convolve2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html)